# Minimum and maximum of two lists using Python

Tags: python

Let's say I have two lists (containing 2D positions):

```py
pos1 = [100, 400]
pos2 = [200, 300]
```

Now I want to store the min `x` and the min `y` of these positions into `min` and `max`:

```py
min_ = [min_x, min_y]
max_ = [max_x, max_y]

# in this case:

min_ = [100, 300]
max_ = [200, 400]
```

---

Actually, I am using a code like this:

```py
min_ = []
max_ = []

min_.append(min(pos1[0], pos2[0]))
min_.append(min(pos1[1], pos2[1]))
max_.append(max(pos1[0], pos2[0]))
max_.append(max(pos1[1], pos2[1]))
```

Is there a more efficient way to do that?

Comment: `min_x, max_x = sorted(pos1[0], pos2[0])`, same for `y`

Comment: Yeah, but it works only if I have two positions (but in this case this functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
min_ = [min(first, second) for first, second in zip(pos1, pos2)]
max_ = [max(first, second) for first, second in zip(pos1, pos2)]
```

By the way same but (maybe) a bit less readable:

```
min_ = [min(coords) for coords in zip(pos1, pos2)]
max_ = [max(coords) for coords in zip(pos1, pos2)]
```

NOTE: in terms of efficiency the two solutions are probably comparable this one simply avoids some code repetition.

Comment: The second approach is ***not*** less readable (IMO) and also generalizes for more coordenates

Comment: It's only that in those cases the more "sexy", short list-comprehension falls short over a good old-fashioned loop that only iterates the `zip` once and constructs both resulting lists...

Answer (score 1):

Don't use keywords like `min` and `max` for variable names.
You could use list-comprehension and `zip`:

```
minimum_values = [min(x,y) for x,y in zip(pos1, pos2)]
```

Comment: If we're talking about good variable naming conventions, I'd recommend not using `x` and `y` for the comprehension variables when they both refer to vectors which *each* have a respective X and Y coordinate.

Comment: OP uses `min_` and `max_`. that doesn't override the built-ins...

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing a lot with coordinates, you'll find [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) makes a lot of these sorts of things more ergonomic.

```
import numpy as np

pos1 = np.array([100, 400])
pos2 = np.array([200, 300])

min_ = np.min([pos1, pos2], 0)
max_ = np.max([pos1, pos2], 0)
```